# Parse JSON into a MONGODB docment

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to `JAVA` and `MONGODB` and have been learning both to try and understand if these technologies would meet my requirements for a product.

I am currently stuck in a point where I am not able to insert documents(records) from `JAVA` into my `MONGODB` collection.

I am using the new `MONGODB` `version 3.0`.

Code so far

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("Collection");
String json = "{'class':'Class10', 'student':{'name':'Alpha', 'sex':'Female'}, {'name':'Bravo', 'sex':'Male'}}";
```

I have found code to convert this to a `DBObject` type.

```js
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);
```

But I guess the new version of `MONGODB` does not have the insert method but instead has the `insertOne method`.

`coll.insertOne()` requires that the input be in the Document format and does not accept the DBObject format.

```js
coll.insertOne((Document) dbObject);
```

gives the error

```
com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to org.bson.Document
```

Can someone help me with the right type casting and give me a link where I could find and learn the same?

Regards.

Comment: I think problem with this `coll.insertOne((Document) dbObject);` can you check this `coll.insertOne(dbObject);` without casting `Document` and then insert.

Comment: Check this link    http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/

Comment: If you use DBCollection instead of MongoCollection<>, you can use insert(DBObject) on it.

Comment: Hi Yogesh, I tried what you mentioned but there is a definitive error coming on Eclipse showing that there is a type cast error. Changed as per you suggestion and the error I get is "The method insertOne(Document) in the type MongoCollection<Document> is not applicable for the arguments (DBObject)"

Comment: Hi Ranjit, Yes. I found this link that would convert JSON data into DBObject. However, after the successful conversion, I am not able to insert the same into collection. Mongo version 2.10 has the insert method but this is not there in the Mongo version 3.0. In 3.0 there is an insertOne method which only accepts in the Document format.

Comment: Hi Simon, To use DBCollection, I would have to change the method in which the DB was selected from getDatabase which returns type MongoDatabase to a deprecated method getDB. If I use getDB, everything falls into place and most tutorials would work. However the problem is that I want to use the newer methods as present in MongoDB 3.0. Any suggestions? Should nothing work, I do plan on using the deprecated method and continue with my development.

Answer (score 9):

Use the static [parse(String json)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/org/bson/Document.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method that's defined in the Document class.

Comment: But while parsing a JSON string , the thrown error is org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid JSON number

Answer (score 7):

- The problem is that you are using an older
  version(BasicDBObject) that is not compatible with version 3.0.
- But there is a way for 2.0 users to use BasicDBObject.An overload of 
  the getCollection method allows clients to specify a different class 
  for representing BSON documents.

The following code must work for you.

```
MongoCollection<BasicDBObject> coll = db.getCollection("Collection", BasicDBObject.class);

coll.insertOne(dbObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used google gson for convert pojo to json, and this is work perfect.

```
private final MongoCollection<Document> collection;

//my save
    String json = gson.toJson(data);//data is User DTO, just pojo!
    BasicDBObject document = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(json);
    collection.insertOne(new Document(document));
```

Java mongodb driver version is 3.4.2